# beginner: on reading in from file and using istringstream

Tags: c++, istringstream

I have never used istringstream before.  I have only split lines before with 1 delimiter so I don't know how to use istringstream.  I am splitting lines from a file that look like this:

Table, Wanted, 100

Car, For Sale, 5000

I need to split the strings and then create an array of structs.  I have a struct set up already I just don't know how to split the strings. My struct is called item and has types: string type, bool sale, double price. For sale, I want it to say 1 if it is for sale and 0 if it is wanted. 
Basically, I want to split it so I can create new variables, type, sale, and price and then create a newItem{type, sale, price} in my item struct and go from there. An example of the code would be extremely helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you try your best first? Before we try ours?  That's fair, right?

Comment: It seems you want to parse a csv file.  Plenty of information about how to do that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

A simple method to split a string using a delimiter character is to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

```
std::string line = "Table, Wanted, 100"; // Let's say you have read a line from file.
std::istringstream input{line};          // Create an input stream from string.

// Read all characters up until the delimiter ',' on each iteration.
for (std::string token; std::getline(input, token, ',');) {
    /* Do something with each token... */
}
```

<kbd>**[Live example](http://ideone.com/dGQcU1)**</kbd>